# Factorial simplification

Tags: factoring, factorial

How can I work with this?
$$\frac{(3n)!}{(3(n+1))!}$$
I really don't know how to open this fatorial and then, simplify it.

Actually, I have to calculate the limit when $n\to\infty$.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(3(n + 1))! = (3n + 3)! = (3n)!(3n + 3)(3n+2)(3n+1)$$

$$\frac{(3n)!}{(3(n+1))!} = \frac{\require{cancel}\cancel{(3n)!}}{\cancel{(3n)!}(3n + 3)(3n+2)(3n+1)} = \dfrac 1{(3n + 3)(3n+2)(3n+1)}$$ which goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: You're very welcome!